# Edits less than six characters

Tags: discusión, ediciones

On several of the betas, I've run into the "Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters" rule. Five characters or less can make a big difference, especially in technical questions on a short word or phrase. What should be done in cases where a significant edit should be made, but it is under the character minimum?

Comment: I hate the 6-character rule, too... everywhere.  But the powers-that-be won't budge. And although I disagree with them, I understand and respect their reasons.  The solution is to post a comment, and/or wait until you have enough rep to bypass the limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always leave a comment to let the OP know and fix the mistakes. Once they have done so you can delete the comments that led to it.

During *private beta* when you get to 500 rep you don't have to worry about the 6 characters rule anymore.

And during *public beta* the required rep is 1000.

Comment: @Flimzy I tried to vote up your addition but I can't vote up my own post! (-: